# Plot in R: connecting a point to the axis

Tags: r, plot

Let's suppose I have a simple plot:

```
plot(0.3, 0.3, lwd=7)
```

I want to draw two lines connecting the (0.3, 0.3) point with the X and Y axis. `abline` is not useful here, as it goes over the point. 
I would like to apply the same solution when I have 6-7 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `segments` function:

Let's say the coordinates of your points are stored in vectors `x` and `y`, you can do:

```
plot(x, y, lwd=7)
segments(x0=x, y0=0, x1=x, y1=y) # segments from x axis to points
segments(x0=0, y0=y, x1=x, y1=y) # segments from y axis to points
```

**Example with your point**

```
x <- y <- 0.3
plot(x, y, lwd=7)
segments(x, 0, x, y)
segments(0, y, x, y)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Is there a way to do the same when I have, let's say, 10 points?       I can "program" it, but is there a single option to do that?

Comment: @David_grx, yes, the solution I gave is for any number of points, I just use your "single point example" as example but `x` and `y` are 2 vectors of any numbers of coordinates, so, in the case of 10 points, you can do `x <- c(x1, x2, x3, ..., x10) ; y <- c(y1, y2, y3, ..., y10)`.

Comment: @David_grx, so, did you try with several points and did it work ?